# have userform call function from main module and Populate imageBox

Tags: excel, vba, userform

```
Public Function LoadImage() As Object

  For Each pics In sheetImages.Shapes
    If (CStr(pics.Name) = CStr(currpartImage)) Then
      Me.ImagePreview.Picture =PictureFromShape(sheetImages.Shapes(currImage))
      Me.ImagePreview.PictureSizeMode = 3
      currImageRow = sheetImages.Shapes(currpartImage).TopLeftCell.row + 1
    End If
  Next
End Function
```

I am trying to have a userform call this Function from my main module and have it set the imagebox as the shape... it runs fine when this function is in the userform code but i am trying to avoid having to copy this code for all my userforms.... when i put this function in the userform- "Me." & "as Object" are removed

Comment: `Me` is only valid inside an object module (userform/sheet/class) and refers to the object instance itself (in your case the userform).  If you want to access some specific item (control etc) from code in a regular module then you should add that as a parameter to your function, and pass the item from the calling code. Also it would make more sense for your code to be Sub and not a function, since it doesn't return a value.

Comment: how would i access the image control? would it be something like Userform.Controls(ImagePreview).Picture =  ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a parameter to your routine:

```
Public Sub LoadImage(imageControl as Object) As Object
  For Each pics In sheetImages.Shapes
    If (CStr(pics.Name) = CStr(currpartImage)) Then
      imageControl .Picture =PictureFromShape(sheetImages.Shapes(currImage))
      imageControl .PictureSizeMode = 3
      currImageRow = sheetImages.Shapes(currpartImage).TopLeftCell.row + 1
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Calling from your Form:

```
LoadImage Me.ImagePreview
```

You will also need to pass any other items which are referenced in `LoadImage` but which are not in scope outside of the userform.